# IzPack Installer Fails - InvocationTargetException

Tags: izpack

I have an application that deploys various dependencies that I've packaged up with IzPack.

The compilation process works fine, but when I try to execute the installer jar file (GUI mode)  `java -jar .\installer\cot-installer.jar` I receive the following exception in the console:

```
SEVERE: com.izforge.izpack.api.exception.IzPackException: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

If I run in 'console mode' (`-console`) I don't see any errors.

I have tried other versions of Java which break even building the package as well.

### Environment

- Windows 10

### Java Version Info

- java version "1.8.0_271"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode)

### IzPack Info

- Version 5.3.1

### install.xml

```xml
<izpack:installation version="5.0"
                     xmlns:izpack="http://izpack.org/schema/installation"
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xsi:schemaLocation="http://izpack.org/schema/installation http://izpack.org/schema/5.0/izpack-installation-5.0.xsd">
    
    <info>
        <appname>my app</appname>
        <appversion>1.0</appversion>
        <javaversion>1.8</javaversion>
        <authors>
            <author name="my name" email="my email"></author>
        </authors>
        <requiresjdk>no</requiresjdk>
        <uninstaller path="$INSTALL_PATH/uninstaller" name="cot_uninstaller.jar" write="yes"></uninstaller>
        <summarylogfilepath>$INSTALL_PATH/InstallationSummary.htm</summarylogfilepath>
        <writeinstallationinformation>no</writeinstallationinformation>
    </info>
    
    <locale>
        <langpack iso3="eng"/>
    </locale>
    
    <guiprefs width="800" height="600" resizable="no">
        <laf name="substance">
            <os family="windows" />
            <os family="unix" />
            <param name="variant" value="mist-silver" />
        </laf>
        
        <modifier key="useHeadingPanel" value="yes" />
        <modifier key="headingFontSize" value="1.5"/>
        <modifier key="headingBackgroundColor" value="0x00ffffff"/>
        <modifier key="headingPanelCounter" value="text"/>
        <modifier key="headingPanelCounterPos" value="inFooter"/>
    </guiprefs>
    
    <resources>
        <res id="userInputSpec.xml" src="userInputSpec.xml" parse="yes" type="xml"/>
        <res id="userInputLang.xml_eng" src="userInputLang.xml_eng" />
    </resources>
    
    <panels>
        <panel classname="HelloPanel"/>
        <panel classname="TargetPanel"/>
        <panel classname="UserInputPanel" id="nifiPanel"/>
        <panel classname="PacksPanel"/>
        <panel classname="SummaryPanel"/>
        <panel classname="InstallPanel"/>
        <panel classname="ShortcutPanel"/>
        <panel classname="SimpleFinishPanel"/>
    </panels>
    
    <packs>
        ...packs
    </packs>
    
</izpack:installation>
```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently, hidden behind the original error message, I had an issue with my userInput.xml configuration. After I fixed that, the issue was resolved.
The specific issue was a  element that was missing a mandatory  element. Missed the "required" part in the documentation.
UGH...